# Array out of bounds exception in Java while implementing the knapsack algorithm

Tags: java, knapsack-problem

I am a beginner to Java programming, and I was trying to implement knapsack algorithm by dynamic programming and it works perfectly for few inputs, but for few inputs it throws an exception. The code is

```
package knapsack3;

import java.util.Scanner;
 
/** Class Knapsack **/

public class knapsack3
{
    
   
    public void solve(int wt[], int val[], int M, int n)
    {
        int nob = 25;
        int i,j;
        int v[][]=new int[nob][nob];
        for(i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=M;j++)
            {
                if(i==0||j==0)
                {
                    v[i][j]=0;
                }
                else if(j-wt[i]<0)
                {
                    v[i][j]=v[i-1][j];
                }
                else
                {
                    v[i][j]=Math.max(v[i-1][j],val[i]+v[i-1][j-wt[i]]);
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("\n Final Profit(value)---> "+v[n-1][M]);
    }
    /** Main function **/
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Knapsack Algorithm Test\n");
  
        knapsack3 ks = new knapsack3();
        
        System.out.println("Enter number of elements ");
        int n = scan.nextInt();
 
        int wt[] = new int[n + 1];
        int val[] = new int[n + 1];
 
        System.out.println("\nEnter weight for "+ n +" elements");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            wt[i] = scan.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("\nEnter value for "+ n +" elements");
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            val[i] = scan.nextInt();
 
        System.out.println("\nEnter knapsack weight ");
        int M = scan.nextInt();

        ks.solve(wt, val, M, n);
       scan.close();
    }
    
}
```

the exception is

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25
at knapsack3.knapsack3.solve(knapsack3.java:22)
at knapsack3.knapsack3.main(knapsack3.java:61)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of your array

```
int nob = 25;
int v[][]=new int[nob][nob];
```

is hardcoded to size 25, but you then use a for-loop that goes to `n` and `M` (So if you enter a number for `n` or `M` larger than `nob` aka 25 then you will get an out of bounds exception.

Your for-loops should always use the array in them like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < v.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < v[i].length; j++){}
}
```

to avoid this issue.

*edit* 
However, Your real issue, now that I re look at the question is that your for-loop does this:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
```

If you have `i <= n` starting at 0 you will run this loop 26 (not 25) times.  Since I am assuming your `n` is 25 since you hard-coded `nob` to 25.

Also

```
for(int j = 0; j <= M; j++)
```

means that you will go from 0 to M (Knapsack size) which I assume is almost always above 25, so this will always cause an out of bounds exception because you hard code the size of the array.

Comment: nope, the number 25 does not matter as i took care that i did not give more than 25 elements

Comment: Right but if you give 25 elements you will still go out of bounds, as you are going from 0 to 25 (INCLUDING 25) so you will be using `v[25][25]` which is out of bounds for your array

Comment: ok, try the modified program(with your corrections) and run the program, maybe i am missing something, thanx :-)

Comment: You are welcome if this worked please select it as the answer.  Have a great day.

Comment: sure i will :-), please tell me if you are successful with the program, if yes please comment the answer

Comment: Can you give me an example of an input that fails?  That would be helpful is making sure my solution is accurate.  (AKA how many items, their weights/associated values and my knap sack weight.  Thanks

Comment: 24 elements, weights 29
59
99
200
201
249
300
350
360
390
499
500
1000
20
30
40
50
54
100
108
110
120
150
700
 profit:-29
59
99
200
201
249
300
350
360
390
499
500
1000
16
24
33
42
25
86
50
95
104
131
623

Comment: Ok so I ran your program, like I said anything over 25 or 25 will crash your program.  So when I say my Knapsack's weight is 25 I get an exception due to `int M = scan.nextInt();` and then `for(j=0;j<=M;j++)` So if M (Knapsack weight) is 25 or above it will go out of bounds on your array `v` since you have its size set to `v[25][25]`

Also for that example you just posted those weights are well above 25, which is definitely the reason you are going out of bounds.  `for(j=0;j<=M;j++)` is taking j from 0 to the weight of your Knapsack which is well over 25 (What you set `v`s size to).

Comment: please comment the complete final working code here :-)

Comment: I answered your question you should accept the answer and make the corrections yourself.  It is a good learning experience.